# How to add more information to PayPal button?

Tags: html, paypal, subscription

I created a paypal subscription button, but I do not know how to add id number for every product.

The code

```html
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="PULBECSY5HQ2W">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hosted button.  You will not be able to add additional fields directly to the HTML for a hosted button.  Instead, you'll need to make a non-hosted button by unchecking the box for Save at PayPal during the button creation procedure.

This will allow you to add as many [standard variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) as you want, but would not be as secure as a hosted button.

If you want full flexibility plus security you'll need to switch to using the [APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/).

Comment: I did "item_name" standard variables but without unchecking the box for save is this good? Thanks Drew Angell

Comment: I don't think that's going to pass properly because you're using a hosted button.  You can give it a try, though.  I know there are a couple of parameters that will work with hosted buttons.  Most of them you have to include in the "advanced" section of the button builder, though.